Cannot find symchk.exe
I have windows SDK 10 installed through Visual Studio. I am supposed to have symchk.exe under C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64. I need this to load symbols from command line. I tried installing new SDKs but can never find this .exe anywhere. How can I get this file ?

This question is similar to: Location of symchk. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I tried to follow the steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk but can't install it because it's already installed
